# Craft's control panel search function returning inconsistent results

Tags: craft3, search

When I search for titles of entries in the Craft control panel, I get odd results:

I have an entry called ***Fake Story about the Economy***.

If I search for that exact title, I get no results.

If I search for ***Fake Story about***, I get no results.

If I search for ***Fake Story***, the entry ***Fake Story about the Economy*** is returned.

If I search for ***Fake Story the Economy***, the entry ***Fake Story about the Economy*** is returned.

The results are similar for other entries in that channel. For example, I have an entry called ***Is it still business as usual?***. The only way I can find it is if I leave out the word *still* when I type it (***Is it business as usual?***).

Other channels seem to be working fine.

This is of course affecting my ability to build a working search form on the front end as well.

Craft 3.3.19

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses [a list of stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes) when performing full-text searches. As you can see, *about* and *still* are in there... At the top of the page they say:

> False hits or misses might occur for stopword lookups...

I think this is the issue here. One way to get around it in your case is to add the below in your `config/general.php` ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#defaultsearchtermoptions)):

```
'defaultSearchTermOptions' => [
    'subLeft' => true,
],
```

If the above helps, another thing you can try is to change the storage engine your `searchindex` table from MyISAM to InnoDB. That would allow you to remove what you've added in your `config/general.php` but would require you to have at least MySQL v5.6+.

Comment: MildlyGeeky in the discord server suggested defaultSearchTermOptions too. I tried that and saw no change, but this time it seems to fix it, so I guess you're right.

Thank you!